# STM32L011 - Use BOOT0 pin as GPIO

Tags: arm, boot, stm32, gpio

I have an STM32L011 chip in a project and I need to use PB9-BOOT0 pin as GPIO.

I understand that I need to modify the `FLASH_OPTR` register and set `nBOOT0` and `nBOOT_SEL` bits to 1 (page 53 and 108 in reference manual are relevant here).

I'm having trouble understanding how I can set the contents of this register. I've grep-d the STM32Cube code package for `FLASH_OPTR` and the only files containing that are the `stm32l011xx.h` and `stm32l0xx_hal_flash_ex.c` files. And there isn't anything related to the `BOOT0` settings in the header file.

I assume this needs to be compiled into the code that is written to the flash, since the startup code starts by examining this register. Thus writing the register via the HAL flash driver after the chip has started code execution is pointless, right?

Reference manual: http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/21/bd/0f/bd/1c/88/40/f0/DM00108282.pdf/files/DM00108282.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00108282.pdf

Comment: You'd typically program the option bytes the same way you program the rest of the flash - you're probably not doing _that_ in code either ;)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the helpful comment...

I'm using OpenOCD to flash a .hex file to the device. What's confusing me though, is that if I read 4 bytes from the flash at offset 0x1C (as stated on page 108 in the reference manual), I get all zeroes.

Also, another thing confusing me is that the startup code that checks to see where to boot from reads from offset 0x04.

edit: can't put the code here in the comment

Comment: Hmm, looks like there's some funky mechanism for software to read the option bytes back from a completely different address - see section 3.8.1.